# Risks of running my own java code on a production server

Tags: java

I work as an operation engineer in a telecom company, i have several servers under my responsibility, and my main task is to perform the "daily health check" for those, part of that is to compare some values with the previous ones, i am considering different options to plot the data, i need your help to evaluate the risks of running my own small java program on those servers considering that i am far from being the best developer out there, for example if i somehow start an endless loop or i don't free the resources that i allocate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why write your own? There are a bazillion products on the market that can do this.

Comment: thank you for your response, those are production servers, i can't install what ever i want there, but let's assume that i can get the approval to install or run a product, what are the risks, if the product fails (or my script that will uses the product) is it possible that it will impact the other critical programs on the server or even crash the server, i want to know if things are "isolated" in java. i can eliminated any potential risk by making a code that is executed on the client side but prefer the plots to be generated on the server and sent to me and the managers as pictures instead.

Comment: It is beyond sanity to think that you could not use a well understood off-the-shelf product but would be able to run arbitrary code in production. The opposite is true in any reasonable environment.

Comment: Agreed. It make no sense that you cannot use a well understood, mature product for this but are allowed to install your own "home grown" application. That is decidedly counter intuitive.

Comment: i know that it doesn't make much sense, but that is how it works here, people use some shell scripts and that made me assume that it is almost risk free, but when it comes to installing an app it sounds risky to me, i'm careful because the failure will without a doubt cost me my job, so i am simply looking for an answer to this simple question: can a java program written by me or someone else damage the server? i mean i already know that java is executed in a JVM, i want to know if that makes it safe or risk free? thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java program is unlikely to damage the server unless it is written to do something that would damage the server.

The JVM allocates a contiguous block of memory on start up, called Heap Space. You use parameters to control the minimum and maximum size of the Heap; I forget what the defaults are but they’re not very big. If you run out of heap, your Java program will crash or run very poorly but everything else should be unaffected. If there isn’t enough memory for the heap to start with, your JVM probably will not start (this is a platform dependent implementation issue). You don’t directly “free resources that you allocate” in Java, but this would be the closest thing to what would happen if you didn’t do that.

The JVM can potentially use 100% of server CPU when executing code. If you put in an endless loop that doesn’t do anything useful that can eat all of the CPU on that machine. This is probably bad for your server, so try not to do that.

Do you plan to do any concurrency? Spin up any separate threads? Call any native libraries with JNI? Execute independent processes? Those are all things that can cause scary crashes that are hard to figure out if you do them wrong. Since you don’t feel confident in your own abilities, I’ll tell you right now not to pursue this plan if any of what you are thinking of involves any of those things.

Other than that, it should be low risk as long as you are certain nobody else will be able to execute this program arbitrarily, e.g. spin up a dozen instances of it in order to crash your server. That’s a really big assumption so spy out should be absolutely sure that it applies here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, that was the answer i was looking for, in my case i decided to use html/js (d3) for now, so almost nothing is executed on the server.